# Designing a database with complex dependencies? (Related to scheduling)

Tags: database-design, scheduled-tasks

I'm seeking to design a database to store information on some complex dependencies and could really use a point in the right direction. My googling hasn't turned up anything relevant, but perhaps you have a great web link.

To provide context, it's around job scheduling and will feed analysis. No, I am not looking to create a job scheduler.

Some notes about the data

- The data can be recursive. Job C is dependent on Job B that's dependent on Job A
- There can be one to many dependencies: Job C could be dependent on Job B1 AND Job B2
- There can be complicated dependencies: Job C could be dependent on (Job B1 OR Job B2) AND Job A
- There can be a confounding variable...time: Job A or 10 AM

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the approaches:

[image: suggestion]

```
CREATE TABLE job (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title character varying NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_job
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- simple job-job dependency, time-based dependency, complex job-job-dependency construct
CREATE TABLE dependency_type (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title character varying NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_dependency_type
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
COMMENT ON TABLE dependency_type IS 'simple job-job dependency, time-based dependency, complex job-job-dependency construct';

-- AND, OR, XOR
CREATE TABLE operator_type (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title character varying NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_operator_type
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
COMMENT ON TABLE operator_type IS 'AND, OR, XOR';

CREATE TABLE dependency (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    type_id integer NOT NULL,
    job_id integer,
    depend_on_job_id integer,
    depend_on_dependency_id integer,
    operator_type_id integer,
    condition varchar,
    CONSTRAINT pk_dependency
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE dependency
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dependency_depend_on_dependency_id
        FOREIGN KEY (depend_on_dependency_id)
        REFERENCES dependency (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE dependency
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dependency_depend_on_job_id
        FOREIGN KEY (depend_on_job_id)
        REFERENCES job (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE dependency
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dependency_job_id
        FOREIGN KEY (job_id)
        REFERENCES job (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE dependency
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dependency_operator_type_id
        FOREIGN KEY (operator_type_id)
        REFERENCES poperator_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE dependency
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dependency_type_id
        FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
        REFERENCES dependency_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So, for cases you described:

**No 1.** Job C is dependent on Job B that's dependent on Job A

```
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, job_id, depend_on_job_id) VALUES (SIMPLE, JOB B, JOB A);
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, job_id, depend_on_job_id) VALUES (SIMPLE, JOB C, JOB B);
```

**No 2.** Job C could be dependent on Job B1 AND Job B2

```
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, depend_on_job_id) VALUES (SIMPLE, JOB B2);
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, job_id, depend_on_job_id, depend_on_dependency_id, operator_type_id) VALUES (COMPLEX, JOB C, JOB B1, DEPENDENCY D1 (from previous insert), AND);
```

**No 3.** Job C could be dependent on (Job B1 OR Job B2) AND Job A

```
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, depend_on_job_id) VALUES (SIMPLE, JOB B2);
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, depend_on_job_id, depend_on_dependency_id, operator_type_id) VALUES (COMPLEX, JOB B1, DEPENDENCY D1 (from previous insert), OR);
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, job_id, depend_on_job_id, depend_on_dependency_id, operator_type_id) VALUES (COMPLEX, JOB C, JOB A, DEPENDENCY D2 (from previous insert), AND);
```

**No 4.** Job C could be dependent on Job A or 10 AM

```
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, condition) VALUES (TIME-BASED, '10 AM');
INSERT INTO dependency (type_id, job_id, depend_on_job_id, depend_on_dependency_id, operator_type_id) VALUES (COMPLEX, JOB C, JOB A, DEPENDENCY D1 (from previous insert), OR);
```

There may be updates to this model: you may want to split `depend_on_job_id` and `depend_on_dependency_id` into multiple columns (`depend_on_job1_id`, `depend_on_job2_id`, etc). This would reduce the depth of the tree is some cases (Like case **No 2.** which could be then implemented with only one `INSERT`). And, of course, the model skips on indexes, unique keys, etc.

Also, reading this tree with SQL is a completely different story.